# Zend Framework Translation for Arabic not working on linux server

Tags: zend-framework, zend-translate

I've developed an application in Zend Framework and I am translating it to Arabic. It is working fine on my local Windows machine. When I upload it to a Linux machine I am getting no text using the view translate function.

I am currently using the CSV Adapter for translation. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you manually load translation files make sure you did not hardcode the paths with windows backslashes? make sure you use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` for cross platform compatibility.

Comment: make sure the encoding is UTF8 in your server application...

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and I think the root cause is that the PHP fgetcsv function that Zend Translate library uses to parse CSV files doesn't work properly with UTF-8 text.

I found that the problem was solved if I put double quotes around the text value in the translations .csv file, for example, in my case, if I changed the line:

`MWBtnFind;ابحث`

to

`MWBtnFind;"ابحث"`

it worked just fine